# Mongoid query retrieving embedded object using '$in' operator

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm very beginner of mongoid, so I apology for the basic question.

I'm looking for an mongoid statement which throw the mongoDB query like below:

```
db.mycollection.find({"status.user.name": {$in:["jack","mary"]}}
```

There are two documents in mycollection in mongoDB

```
{ "status": {"user: {:name : "jack"}} }
{ "status": {"user: {:name : "mary"}} }
```

I tried below queries with mongoid, but it did not fetch any document:

```
MyCollection.where("status.user.name" => {'$in' => ["jack","mary"]})
MyCollection.in("status.user.name" =>  ["jack","mary"])
```

#### update on 2013/05/04

I'm sorry. I did not grasp the actual situation when I submit the question. But now I understand what happened and solved the issue. I update the question for those struggling the same issue.

The problem came from my misunderstanding of **"embedding"** and **"referencing"**.

In the above situation, `user` is embedded in `mycollection`. Then, the `in` method can fetch all of two documents.

```
MyCollection.in("status.user.name" => ["jack", "mary"]).size
=> 2
```

But, in my actual situation, `mycollection` just referenced the `user` collection.

```
mycollection collection
{ "status": {"user_id": xyzxyz} }
{ "status": {"user_id": abcabc} }
user collection
{ "_id":xyzxyz, "name": "jack" }
{ "_id":abcabc, "name": "mary" }
```

That's why I couldn't fetch any documents with `where` or `in` method. In my understanding, I can't fetch `user` documents via `mycollection` with only one query becaus MongoDB isn't a RDBMS and doesn't support such kind of relation query.

```
MyCollection.in("status.user.name" => ["jack", "mary"]).size
=> 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
MyCollection.in(status.user.name: [ "jack", "mary" ]).find();
```